# How to pass "Evil Awoken" mission of prologue campaign on Brutal?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm playing "Evil Awoken" mission of "Legacy of Void" prologue campaign and have difficulties on the 2nd part of the mission: upon the destruction of "Void Catalyst" my units don't have fire power to kill appearing enemies quickly and taking damage. Been under the ticking time pressure, I don't have time to restore sheilds health and eventually my units die.

How to pass the 2nd part of the missions?

Comment: Don't try to kill anything.  Just use stalkers as meat shields at the second part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Abuse blink stalkers like crazy, blinking back the hurt ones as soon as they lose all of their shields during fights. After the second part, bring your Stalkers along as best as you can, but don't really worry about them and don't even bother trying to fight. Just run/blink by everything, with a special focus on keeping Zeratul as healthy as possible and not getting blocked or stopped at all. It might take a few tries, but for me it was one of the easier missions on Brutal.

Comment: Heh, after your suggestion I did that from the 3rd try :) thanks! :)